# Robocopy option to force copy fail if destination folder does NOT exist

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to use Robocopy as part of my backup procedures, whereby backup files are copied from one disk to another (for secondary and tertiary backups). I basically have one key external drive for primary backups, and then various of the backups get siphoned off to other disks, depending on which disk it is. I want to develop a sequence of Robocopy commands in a batch file that I can use in any situation, so that if the Robocopy command tries to copy a folder from the source to a destination drive where there is no matching folder, it automatically FAILS and moves on to the next command. Robocopy by default creates the destination folder if it does not already exist, and I want to switch this default OFF if at all possible.

Comment: You can run the robocopy commands from a powershell script, and use powershell to test for folder existence, error checking and conditional logic.